# OnetoOne (primary_key=Tue) to ForeignKey in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a OnetoOne field  with primary_key=True in a model.
Now I want to change that to a ForeignKey but cannot since there is no 'id'.

From this:

> user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

To this:

> user1 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='questionnaire', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Showing this while makemigrations:

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to historicaluserquestionnaire without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
>   Please select a fix:
>    1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
>    2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

So how to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: What if you try allowing nulls like  null=True, or set a default user as default=<have your default user here>

Comment: No its the same thing because primary key was True so there was no id to those objects

Answer (score 1):

just delete your previous migrations

```
e.g 

    migrations:
          |
          |- 001.initail.py
          |- 002.examplefiles.py
```

you just have to delete you most recent migrations and

run the command

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```

Comment: No, that doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

Django models have a default **ID** attribute. Since you changed the model, the previous data records has now conflicts with your new column attributes because when previous records were added, there were no  ForeignKey. Remember, In your foreignkey, null values are not allowed. There are multiple fixes to your solution. Follow these step one-by-one and see what resolves your eror.

- Delete your migrations file and run migrations again

> Set NULL=True in your foreign key
>
> OR
>
> Delete previous records of the table to resolve the conflict, so that when you run migrations, it adds a default value of id itself

instead of deleting,  you can also try and change your migrations files directly like this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29074241/11979793

Comment: Problem is not with the migrations of ForeignKey field, problem lies in the delete of OnetoOne field since the primary_key is True

Comment: Does this thread help? 


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055784/what-is-the-best-approach-to-change-primary-keys-in-an-existing-django-app

Comment: Not that relevant, anyway I have solved it the bad way, by making a new models with the fields I wanted and tranfer the data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your trying to remove the primary key, but Django is then going to add a new primary key called "id".  This is non-nullable and unique, so you can't really provide a one-off default.

The easiest solution is to just create a new model and copy your table over in a SQL migration, using the old user_id to populate the id field.  Be sure to reset your table sequence to avoid collisions.

Comment: Didn't wanted to do that, thats why I have posted this
It seems like there is no other option to do this
Thanks!

Comment: No matter how you handle it, don't forget to reset the sequence in your database so that you avoid collisions.  If you want to try another way you are going to have to use a [SeparateDatabaseAndState](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/migration-operations/#separatedatabaseandstate) operation to add the id field state and probably just copy the user_id column in the database to id.